# Javafx concatenation of multiple StringProperty

Tags: string, javafx, concatenation, observable

Is there a simple way to bind a concatenation of StringProperty objects?

Here is what I want to do:

```
TextField t1 = new TextField();
TextField t2 = new TextField();

StringProperty s1 = new SimpleStringProperty();
Stringproperty s2 = new SimpleStringProperty();
Stringproperty s3 = new SimpleStringProperty();

s1.bind( t1.textProperty() ); // Binds the text of t1
s2.bind( t2.textProperty() ); // Binds the text of t2

// What I want to do, theoretically :
s3.bind( s1.getValue() + " <some Text> " + s2.getValue() );
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do:

```
s3.bind(Bindings.concat(s1, "  <some Text>  ", s2));
```

Here's a complete example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class BindingsConcatTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField tf1 = new TextField();
        TextField tf2 = new TextField();
        Label label = new Label();

        label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.concat(tf1.textProperty(), " : ", tf2.textProperty()));

        VBox root = new VBox(5, tf1, tf2, label);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 150);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Well it seems it does not work. If I bind the StringProperty of a label, it displays :

    `StringProperty [bound, invalid] <some Text> StringPropery [bound, invalid]`

Changing the values of s1 and s2 does not change anything.

Comment: Added a full example. (I'm using JDK 1.8.0_11, fwiw)

Comment: Did you use `+` where I had `,` inside the `concat(...)` call?

Comment: Yes I did.. (Hiding my shame). Thanks a lot, problem solved :)

Comment: Is there a difference between `Bindings.concat` and `textProperty().concat`?

Comment: @BradTurek Not functionally, but `Bindings.concat(...)` is a varargs method, so it's more convenient here (you would need `tf1.textProperty().concat(" : ").concat(tf2.textProperty())`).